# Check input to determine if in list and return a boolean

Tags: haskell

For this question you will implement functions that deal with the transaction history of a portfolio of
stocks. Each transaction is represented by a tuple. For example:
('B', 100, 1104, "VTI", 1)

The elements of this tuple are:
•The first element is a character that is either 'B' or 'S'. This represents whether the transaction
was buying or selling.
•The second element is an integer representing how many units were bought or sold.
•The third element is an integer representing the price per unit that we bought or sold at.
•The fourth element represents the stock that we bought.
•The final element represents the day that the transaction took place on.
So our example transaction says that we bought 100 units of VTI on day 1, and we paid £1104 per unit.
So the total amount that we spent was 100 ×£1104 = £110400.

A transaction log is a list of transactions. For example:

```
type Transaction = (Char, Int, Int, String, Int)

test_log :: [Transaction]

test_log = [('B', 100, 1104, "VTI", 1),

('B', 200, 36, "ONEQ", 3),

('B', 50, 1223, "VTI", 5),

('S', 150, 1240, "VTI", 9),

('B', 100, 229, "IWRD", 10),

('S', 200, 32, "ONEQ", 11),

('S', 100, 210, "IWRD", 12)

]​​​​​​​
```

Write a function stock_test :: String -> Transaction -> Bool that takes a stock
and a transaction log, and returns True if the transaction trades that stock, and False otherwise. For
example:
ghci> stock_test "VTI" ('B', 100, 1104, "VTI", 1)
True
ghci> stock_test "ONEQ" ('B', 100, 1104, "VTI", 1)
False

I was able to write this in Python but can't figure out how to do it in Haskell. Here is my code in Python:

```
def stock_test(stock, log):
 for transaction in log:
   if transaction[3] == stock:
     return True
     return False
```

I was thinking something like this but am a bit stuck:

```
stock_test :: String -> Transaction -> Bool
stock_test = 
   let stocks == stocks = True
                         | transaction_to_string == transaction_to_string = True
                         | otherwise = False
```

Comment: How about `stock_test x (_, _, _, y, _) = x == y`?

Answer (score 0):

If function `stock_test` is to deal with a transaction *log*, its type signature is to be:

```
stock_test :: String -> [Transaction] -> Bool
```

As mentioned in the comments, you would probably start with an auxiliary function that just extracts the stock name:

```
getStockName :: Transaction -> String
getStockName (_, _, _, stockName, _) = stockName
```

**Side note:** This is a bit rough, and in practice you would probably use a Haskell feature known as [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax).

Let's try:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.5: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
 λ> 
 λ> :load q74409725.hs
 [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( q74409725.hs, interpreted )
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> length test_log
 7
 λ> 
 λ> getStockName ('B', 200, 36, "ONEQ", 3)
 "ONEQ"
 λ> 
 λ> map getStockName test_log
 ["VTI","ONEQ","VTI","VTI","IWRD","ONEQ","IWRD"]
 λ>
```

At that point, we just need to test whether the desired stock name lies in the output of library function `map`. Essentially, we need to test whether a given object is part of a given list. This is done thru library function [`elem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem).

Hence:

```
 λ> 
 λ> elem "VTI" (map getStockName test_log)
 True
 λ> 
 λ> elem "ASML" (map getStockName test_log)
 False
 λ>
```

So we can write our `stock_test` function like this:

```
stock_test :: String -> [Transaction] -> Bool
stock_test stockName ts = elem stockName (map getStockName ts)
```

Compared with Python, there is no explicit loop. Function `map` does the looping, and `elem` returns the result. Because of Haskell being a *lazy* language, `elem` can return immediately when a match is found, with its input list being only partially generated.

Note that alternatively, you can also write Python code in Haskell-ish, functional style:

```
$ python3
Python 3.10.8 (main, Oct 12 2022, 00:00:00) [GCC 12.2.1 20220819 (Red Hat 12.2.1-2)] on linux
...
>>> 
>>> ts = []
>>> 
>>> ts.append((0,1, "ASML",2))
>>> ts.append((3,4, "TSMC",5))
>>> 
>>> print(ts)
[(0, 1, 'ASML', 2), (3, 4, 'TSMC', 5)]
>>> 
>>> def stockTest(stockName, trs): return (stockName in (map(lambda t: t[2],trs)))
... 
>>> 
>>> stockTest("CDNS",ts)
False
>>> 
>>> stockTest("ASML",ts)
True
>>>
```